# Dynamically adding sliders to a layout in 2.93?

Tags: python, scripting, rigging, interface

I had need of a URDF visuzlizer on some Windows machines heavily controlled by our IT, so I used the portable zip Blender and made some custom scripts to [view and manipulate the URDF](https://github.com/mcevoyandy/blender_urdf_visualizer). This worked great in 2.90, but now in 2.93 the sliders that I was adding dynamically don't show up any more.[image]

I believe my problem is in one of three places.

1. Where I [dynamically create the class](https://github.com/mcevoyandy/blender_urdf_visualizer/blob/main/load_urdf.py#L97): (Edit to add suggestions by @batFINGER)

```
        # Dynamically create the same class
        JointControllerProperties = type(
            # Class name
            "JointControllerProperties",

            # Base class
            (bpy.types.PropertyGroup, ), {
                "__annotations__": robot.annotations
            },
        )
        URDF_PT_JointControllerPanel.set_joint_names(robot.joint_names)
        bpy.utils.register_class(JointControllerProperties)
        bpy.types.Scene.joint_tool = PointerProperty(type=JointControllerProperties)
        bpy.utils.register_class(URDF_PT_JointControllerPanel)
```

2. where I'm adding the [annotations for the slider](https://github.com/mcevoyandy/blender_urdf_visualizer/blob/main/load_urdf.py#L179):

```
    def GenerateJointAnnotations(self):
        # Generate annotations for dynamically creating the joint sliders.
        # Form should be (dictionary of tuples):
        # annotations: {
        #   'joint0': (
        #        FloatProperty, {
        #            'name': 'j0',
        #            'description': 'desc',
        #            'default': 0,
        #            'min': joint_min,
        #            'max': joint_max,
        #            'update': float_callback}),
        #    <repeated for each joint>
        self.annotations = {}
        for joint in blender_joints:
            if blender_joints[joint]['type'] == 'fixed':
                print('INFO: Fixed joint. Skipping ', joint)
                continue

            self.joint_names.append(joint)
            self.annotations[joint] = (FloatProperty,
            {
                'name': joint,
                'description': joint,
                'default': 0,
                'min': blender_joints[joint]['limit'][0],
                'max': blender_joints[joint]['limit'][1],
                'update': float_callback
            })
        return
```

3. Where I'm [drawing the widget](https://github.com/mcevoyandy/blender_urdf_visualizer/blob/main/joint_controller.py#L20)

```
    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        layout.label(text = 'joint angles')
        scene = context.scene
        joint_tool = scene.joint_tool

        if (len(URDF_PT_JointControllerPanel.joint_names) > 0):
            for joint in URDF_PT_JointControllerPanel.joint_names:
                layout.prop(joint_tool, joint)

        layout.separator()
```

Error with @batFINGER's suggestion:

```
rna_uiItemR: property not found: JointControllerProperties.SY
/home/andy/.config/blender/2.93/scripts/addons/blender_urdf_visualization/joint_controller.py:28
```

I'm guessing my dictionary is no longer correct either, but can't find an example of what this should look like.

Any help would be appreciated... I don't know the blender API well enough to find out where I'm going wrong.

EDIT:
Chagnes thanks to @batFINGER's comments and answer [can be seen here](https://github.com/mcevoyandy/blender_urdf_visualizer/commit/d6b3f64c0eaf30cbe96f9e2f66db7f2f99d59dd6).

Comment: Hello, does it throw an error in the console ? View > System Console

Comment: no, I launch from command line on Ubuntu but don't get anything but the info msgs I print out... I was under the assumption any error msgs would also print out there. Is that not true?

Comment: Suspect it is same issue as https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/239407/python-operator-worked-until-2-93-now-throws-not-propertydeferred-error  Prob requires setting dictionary to `__annotations__` of the property group

Comment: Thanks @batFINGER, I think that's got me going in the right direction... now I'm at least getting some error msgs in the console: `rna_uiItemR: property not found: JointControllerProperties.SY joint_controller.py:28`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Set the `__annotations__` dictionary**

Further to comment

> Suspect it is same issue as
> [Python Operator worked until 2.93, now throws " not _PropertyDeferred" error](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/239407/python-operator-worked-until-2-93-now-throws-not-propertydeferred-error)
> Prob requires setting dictionary to **annotations** of the property
> group

Wrote, before, pasted after edit to question, anyway shows on the right track.
Test example.

```
import bpy

from bpy.types import PropertyGroup
from bpy.props import FloatProperty, PointerProperty
context = bpy.context

annos = {f"float{i}" : FloatProperty(default=i) for i in range(10)}

Foo = type("Foo",
        (PropertyGroup,),
        {"__annotations__" : annos}
        )
        
bpy.utils.register_class(Foo)
bpy.types.Scene.foo = PointerProperty(type=Foo)
```

Python console

```
>>> bpy.app.version
(2, 93, 0)

>>> C.scene.foo.float9
9.0
```

Which after checking is pretty much the example outlined in [2.93 release notes](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/2.93/Python_API) from (probable duplicate) link posted

See the difference to

```
        self.annotations[joint] = (FloatProperty,
        {
            'name': joint,
            'description': joint,
            'default': 0,
            'min': blender_joints[joint]['limit'][0],
            'max': blender_joints[joint]['limit'][1],
            'update': float_callback
        })
```

in that you are setting akin to a partial function  `(FooProperty, propsdict)`

instead of to `FooProperty(**propsdict)`  to wire up the groups  properties as demonstrated above.

Comment: Thanks! working perfectly again.